# TypeError when trying to apply custom loss in a multilabel classification problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to solve a multilabel text classification problem using BERT from huggingface transformers library. The model is defined as follows:

```
def create_model(encoder, nb_classes=3, lr=1e-5):

    # inputs
    input_ids = tf.keras.Input(shape=(512,), ragged=False,
                               dtype=tf.int32, name='input_ids')
    input_attention_mask = tf.keras.Input(shape=(512,), ragged=False,
                                          dtype=tf.int32, name='attention_mask')
    # transformer
    output = encoder({'input_ids': input_ids, 
                      'attention_mask': input_attention_mask})[0]
    Y = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(output)
    Y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(nb_classes, activation='sigmoid')(Y)

    # compilation
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_ids, input_attention_mask], 
                           outputs=[Y])
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr)

    # losses
    # loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
    # loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)

    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, 
                  loss=multilabel_loss, metrics=['acc'])
    model.summary()
    return model
```

As you can see, I tried to use tf.keras.losses, but it did not work (throwing `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'nested_row_splits'`), so I defined a simple cross entropy by hand:

```
def multilabel_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred)
    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, y_pred.dtype)
    cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum((y_true*tf.math.log(y_pred + 1e-8) + (1 - y_true) * tf.math.log(1 - y_pred + 1e-8)),
                                   name='xentropy')
    return cross_entropy
```

The model is created with strategy.scope() as shown below, using 'distil-bert-uncased' as a checkpoint:

```
with strategy.scope():
    encoder = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
    #encoder = TFRobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
    model = create_model(encoder)
```

The labels are binary arrays:

```
163350    [0, 0, 1]
118940    [0, 0, 1]
65243     [0, 0, 1]
30011     [0, 0, 1]
189713    [0, 1, 0]
```

They are combined with tokenized texts into a tf.dataset in a next function:

```
def tf_text_data_prep(df):
    """
    input: takes pandas dataframe
    output: returns tokenized tf.Dataset
    """
    hugging_ds = Dataset.from_pandas(df)
    tokenized_ds = hugging_ds.map(
                      tokenize_function,
                      batched=True,
                      num_proc=strategy.num_replicas_in_sync,
                      remove_columns=["Text", '__index_level_0__'],
                      load_from_cache_file=True 
                      )
    
    # Convert to tensorflow
    tf_dataset = tokenized_ds.with_format("tensorflow")
    features = {x: tf_dataset[x].to_tensor() for x in tokenizer.model_input_names}
    tf_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, tf_dataset["label"]))
    return tf_data
```

The problem is when I launch the training, I get the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-720b4634d50e> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('time', '', 'steps_per_epoch = int(BUFFER_SIZE // BATCH_SIZE)\nprint(\n    f"Model Params:\\nbatch_size: {BATCH_SIZE}\\nEpochs: {EPOCHS}\\n"\n    f"Step p. Epoch: {steps_per_epoch}\\n"\n    f"Initial Learning rate: {INITAL_LEARNING_RATE}"\n)\nhistory = model.fit(\n    train_ds,\n    validation_data=val_ds,\n    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,\n    epochs=EPOCHS,\n    callbacks=callbacks,\n    verbose=1,\n)')

12 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2115             magic_arg_s = self.var_expand(line, stack_depth)
   2116             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2117                 result = fn(magic_arg_s, cell)
   2118             return result
   2119 

<decorator-gen-53> in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    186     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    187     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 188         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    189 
    190         if callable(arg):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.py in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)
   1191         else:
   1192             st = clock2()
-> 1193             exec(code, glob, local_ns)
   1194             end = clock2()
   1195             out = None

<timed exec> in <module>()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1176                 _r=1):
   1177               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1178               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1179               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1180                 context.async_wait()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    887 
    888       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 889         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    890 
    891       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    931       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    932       initializers = []
--> 933       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    934     finally:
    935       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    762     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    763         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 764             *args, **kwds))
    765 
    766     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3048       args, kwargs = None, None
   3049     with self._lock:
-> 3050       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   3051     return graph_function
   3052 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3442 
   3443           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3444           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3445           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3446 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3287             arg_names=arg_names,
   3288             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3289             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3290         self._function_attributes,
   3291         function_spec=self.function_spec,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    997         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    998 
--> 999       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
   1000 
   1001       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    670         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
    671         with OptionalXlaContext(compile_with_xla):
--> 672           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    673         return out
    674 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    984           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    985             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 986               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    987             else:
    988               raise

TypeError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:850 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:840 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1285 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2833 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3608 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:833 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 train_step
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:460 update_state
        metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py:86 decorated
        update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py:177 update_state_fn
        return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py:659 update_state  **
        [y_true, y_pred], sample_weight)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py:546 ragged_assert_compatible_and_get_flat_values
        raise TypeError('One of the inputs does not have acceptable types.')

    TypeError: One of the inputs does not have acceptable types.
```

This same approach worked for ordinary binary classification, but not for multilabel.
I'd appreciate any help regarding the error or the approach in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification` i.e. `ForSequenceClassification` and if you were to see it's summary you will find that it returns a `Dense` output and hence it is not an encoder as you want it.

```
encoder = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
encoder.summary()
'''
Result:
All model checkpoint layers were used when initializing TFBertForSequenceClassification.

Some layers of TFBertForSequenceClassification were not initialized from the model checkpoint at bert-base-uncased and are newly initialized: ['classifier']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.
Model: "tf_bert_for_sequence_classification_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
bert (TFBertMainLayer)       multiple                  109482240 
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_187 (Dropout)        multiple                  0         
_________________________________________________________________
classifier (Dense)           multiple                  1538      
=================================================================
Total params: 109,483,778
Trainable params: 109,483,778
Non-trainable params: 0
'''
```

But you want to use it as `encoder` and hence you would have to do it like this

```
from transformers import TFBertModel
encoder = TFBertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = create_model(encoder)

encoder.summary()
'''
Model: "tf_bert_model_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
bert (TFBertMainLayer)       multiple                  109482240 
=================================================================
Total params: 109,482,240
Trainable params: 109,482,240
Non-trainable params: 0
'''
```

As you can see now you have your encoder as the output from the `Bert`. Now the below line in the `create_model` makes sense but it will give an error cause of below line in `create_model` function

```
output = encoder({'input_ids': input_ids, 
                      'attention_mask': input_attention_mask})[0]
```

This is cause the output at the `0` index is of shape `(batch_size, token_length, embedding)` but we want the value of `[CLS]` token which should be `(batch_size, embedding)` and that is at the `1` index so we have to update to below line:

```
output = encoder({'input_ids': input_ids, 
                      'attention_mask': input_attention_mask})[1]
```

Also, as of now you are fixing the `input_shape` to `512` but we should specify the value to `None` so that we can have variable length input as below

```
input_ids = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None,), ragged=False, dtype=tf.int32, name='input_ids')
    input_attention_mask = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None,), ragged=False, dtype=tf.int32, name='attention_mask')
```

After doing all these change below is the result of a sample run.

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
encoder = TFBertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = create_model(encoder)


inputs = tokenizer('hello world', return_tensors='tf')
model.predict((inputs['input_ids'], inputs['attention_mask']))

'''
Results:
array([[0.7867866 , 0.65974414, 0.45628983]], dtype=float32)
'''
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it was useful as it indeed makes more sense to construct a model using TFBertModel as an encoder. However, it does not solve the initial problem with loss:
- `TypeError: One of the inputs does not have acceptable types.` when using multilabel_loss function
-  `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'nested_row_splits'` when using loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. The issue is resolved.
For anyone who might encounter the same problem, when using data preparation pipeline similar to mine you should convert labels tensor to `EagerTensor` by adding `to_tensor()` for multilabel case. Otherwise, labels tensor of the tf Dataset will contain `tensorflow.python.ops.ragged.ragged_tensor.RaggedTensor` instead of `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor`, which will cause an error during loss computation. So the text_data_prep function should look like that:

```
def tf_text_data_prep(df):
    """
    input: takes pandas dataframe
    output: returns tokenized tf.Dataset
    """
    hugging_ds = Dataset.from_pandas(df)
    tokenized_ds = hugging_ds.map(
                      tokenize_function,
                      batched=True,
                      num_proc=strategy.num_replicas_in_sync,
                      remove_columns=["Text", '__index_level_0__'],
                      load_from_cache_file=True 
                      )
    
    # Convert to tensorflow
    tf_dataset = tokenized_ds.with_format("tensorflow")
    features = {x: tf_dataset[x].to_tensor() for x in tokenizer.model_input_names}
    # add 'to_tensor() to avoid ragged_tensors in multilabel case
    tf_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, 
                                                  tf_dataset["label"].to_tensor()))
    return tf_data
```

Then the training works with both keras.losses or custom ones.